# MongoDB Lookup with Count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

For our non-profit we recruit workers for the summer and track the application information in a Mongo database. I'm trying to limit the query results to only the applications for the current summer, but determine how many summers the applicant has completed. For the query I have two collections: Applicant and Application.

This is what the Application collections look like:

```
    {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6324c900ba6fad569a175778"
  },
  "Applicant": {
    "ID": {
      "$oid": "6324c900ba6fad569a175777"
    }
  },
  "Summer": {
    "ID": {
      "$oid": "932567532532d278b614742a"
    }
  },
  "Status": "Hired",
  ...
},
{
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6424c900ba6fad569a175765"
      },
      "Applicant": {
        "ID": {
          "$oid": "6324c900ba6fad5d9a175777"
        }
      },
      "Summer": {
        "ID": {
          "$oid": "5624c900ba6fadd59a17577e"
        }
      },
      "Status": "Complete",
      ...
    }
```

And this is a sample from the Applicant collection:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6324c900ba6fad5d9a175777"
  },
  "FirstName": "Ted",  
  "LastName": "Doe",
  "CellPhoneNumber": "1234567890",
  "HomePhoneNumber": null,
  "EmailAddress": "ted@somewhere.com",  
  "MailingAddress": {
    "Address1": "123 Some Rd",
    "Address2": "",
    "City": "Somewhere",
    "State": "TX",
    "PostalCode": "23334",
    "Country": "United States"
  },
  ...
}
```

The Application collection includes _id, Summer.ID, Applicant.ID, Status etc while the Applicant collection includes _id, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress etc. What I want to get is a filtered list of Applications that has one row for each current applicant showing FirstName, LastName, Current Status, EmailAddress etc along with a count of all of this person's applications that have a "Completed" status.
An example of the output would be something like:

```
First Last  Status    EmailAddress         Completed Summers
John  Doe   Pending   jdoe@somewhere.com   3
Jane  Smith Hired     janie@somewhere.com  2
Fred  Smith Withdrawn fred@somewhere.com   0
Ted   Doe   Hired     ted@somewhere.com    2
Sally So    Completed sally@somewhere.com  3
```

Using the query below I'm able to get everything except the count of completed summers.

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      Status: "Hired",
      "Summer.ID": ObjectId(
        "932567532532d278b614742a"
      ),
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Applicants",
      localField: "Applicant.ID",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "Applicant",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$Applicant",
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      FirstName: 1,
      LastName: 1,
      Status: 1,
      Phone: "$Applicant.CellPhoneNumber",
      Email: "$Applicant.EmailAddress",
    },
  },
]
```

From here I'm not sure how to proceed.

I tried a different approach that helps me get the count, but then I fail when I try to get the lookup information from the Applicants collection.

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          Status: "Hired",
        },
        {
          Status: "Summer Complete",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$Applicant.ID",
      summers: {
        $sum: 1,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Applicants",
      localField: "Applicant.ID",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "Applicants",
    },
  },
  { $unwind: "$Applicants" },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          { summers: "$summers" },
          "$Applicants",
        ],
      },
    },
  },
]
```

What is the best way to approach solving this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is another lookup stage to retrieve the count of summers from the applications collection matching the applicant's ID that are not the current summer and have status "Complete".

```
{
    $lookup: {
      from: "Applications",
      localField: "Applicant._id",
      foreignField: "Applicant.ID",
      as: "summers",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            "Summer.ID": {
              $ne: ObjectId("932567532532d278b614742a")
            },
            Status: "Complete"
          }
        },
        {
          $count: "count"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$summers"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      FirstName: 1,
      LastName: 1,
      Status: 1,
      Phone: "$Applicant.CellPhoneNumber",
      Email: "$Applicant.EmailAddress",
      PreviousSummers: "$summers.count"
    },
    
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5ASt5mMO_7R)

Comment: Thank you @Joe! This was very helpful. I modified the pipeline slightly because 0 counts would exclude the entire record from the result instead of just showing 0 as the count. I used $facet to accomplish this, but it gives the count as an array. I can work with it though. Here is an example of the result [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TxDMCJ35AEV)

Comment: Shouldn't need facet to accomplish that, just use `{$unwind: "$summers", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}`